# how to drop certain data points from a list

Tags: signal-processing, data-acquisition

```
wo = 2*Pi*50;
tau = 5*Pi;
tstart = 0;
tend = 1;
numpts = 256;
tstep = (tend - tstart)/(numpts - 1);
function = 
N[Table[{t, 
 Exp[-(I wo + tau + 5*\[Pi]) (t)] + 
  Random[NormalDistribution[0, .1]] + 
  I Random[NormalDistribution[0, .1]]}, {t, tstart, tend, tstep}]];

ListPlot[Re[function], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

I want to selectively drop certain time points from the function. For example 10 points from t between 0.10 and 0.15 and drop 40 points from t between 0.60 and 0.80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way might be

```
ListPlot[Re[function], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
newData  = DeleteCases[function,{t_,_}/;(0.1<t<0.15||0.6<t<0.8)];
ListPlot[Re[newData],PlotRange->All,Joined->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How do I specify the number of points which I want to delete. Like not delete all the points but some

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

> ***How do I specify the number of points which I want to delete. Like not delete all the points but some.***

```
tests = {.10 <= # <= .15 & , .6 <= # <= .8 &};
numberofpointstobedropped = {10, 40};
deleted = Join @@ Table[RandomSample[Position[function, _?(i[[1]][#[[1]]] &), {1}, 
   Heads -> False], UpTo[i[[2]]]], {i, Transpose[{tests, numberofpointstobedropped}]}];
dta = SplitBy[Delete[function, deleted], Or @@ Through @ tests @ #[[1]] &];
ListPlot[Re @ dta,  Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
Length /@ {function, Join @@ dta}
```

> {256, 206}

**Original answer:**

```
testF = .10 <= # <= .15 || .6 <= # <= .8 &;
dt = Select[SplitBy[function, testF @ #[[1]]&],   Not @ testF @ #[[1, 1]] &];

ListPlot[Re @ dt,  Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Use the option `PlotStyle->ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]]` to get all three pieces in the same color:

[image]

Comment: How have you defined the number of points to be deleted.

Comment: @tabby_kaur, please see the update.